# jQuery.ajax returns html instead of json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

```
  echo json_encode($mockImageUrl); //I do this in php
```

In js (just the essence):

```
 formdata.append('variation_id', variation.id);
            formdata.append('image_url', s3_url);

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'http://everframe.wordpress.dev/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formdata,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
}
```

and of course the problem is that I get an error "unexpected token.." as it tries to parse html as json. Tried to set  contentType: 'application/json', but it starts returning only 0 without further necessary results.

Yet not sure how I could handle this.

Comment: Try setting the dataType as 'text' to make sure it is returning what you want it to.... Unfortunately without more info as far as what your server is doing it will be hard to provide more help than that. It sounds like your server is serving up html rather than JSON docs though.

Comment: Have you check in dev tools, what is actually returned by your server?

Comment: yes, response headers are Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: @funguy In your PHP script, add `header('Content-type: application/json');` and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: This actually helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot! - @COLDSPEED